# Retrieve ecore model from .jar file

Tags: eclipse, emf

I want to retrieve the compare.ecore model from a .jar file shown in the picture.

[image: Model to retrieve (compare.ecore)]

I tried to copy and paste it in the Eclipse IDE, but it didn't work. I opened the .jar file in the given path with WinRAR, but I can't find the model in the archive.

How can I retrieve this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to retrieve the model. I opened it in Eclipse, made a change and saved it via Save As...

Answer (score 0):

Do not attempt to import the ecore file from the jar.
Rather:

**1.** Window -> Show View -> Other.

[image: show view other]

**2.** Search for "Plug-Ins" -> OK.

[image: search plugins]

**3.** *org.eclipse.emf.compare* -> Import As -> Source Project.

[image]

**4.** Package Explorer -> *org.eclipse.emf.compare* -> model -> compare.ecore

[image]